# using IPv6 Multicast to push a file

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, multicast

I would like to push a file over the network once to reach multiple linux hosts over IPv6 using multicast. (I think, that's the best way)

How can I get my file pushed over IPv6 to multiple systems? I am running under ubuntu 14.04

Comment: either there is nothing, or my google-fu is too weak. I know of udpcast (as used by clonezilla), but it only mentions ipv4.

Comment: https://github.com/Mellanox/sockperf/issues/12

Comment: only v6 multicast support I know of is all routing...maybe widows wds.